# Can't activate a conda environment in windows using a Python script

Tags: python, windows, conda, virtualenv, miniconda

I am running Windows 10 Pro version 22H2 and miniconda 23.3.1. Running this on windows is a requirment for me.

I am trying to activate a conda environment from a python script with the following code:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/name/miniconda3/Scripts")
os.system("conda activate TestEnv")
```

My script is able to successfully change directories, but whenever it tries to actually activate the environment I get the error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I know that there are other stack overflows on this exact error, but most of them are on Linux, and the ones that were on windows didn't have solutions that worked for me.

The frustrating part is that if I copy and paste the commands that my script is running and run them manually everything works with no errors, and I am put into "TestEnv". It just doesn't work with the script. I've already initialized all of the shells, and I've tried other variations of the "conda activate" command such as:

- `activate TestEnv` (works in terminal, but not in script)
- `conda run -n TestEnv` (no errors just doesn't work)
- `conda run -p C:\\Users\\Axion\\miniconda3\\envs\\TestEnv` (no errors, just doesn't work)

Edit:

My goal is to activate the environment and then run a python script within it. The final code might look more like this:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/name/miniconda3/Scripts")
os.system("conda activate TestEnv")
os.system("python script1.py")
os.system("conda activate TestEnv2")
os.system("python script2.py")
```

Comment: Please be aware that even if that did work, it would only activate the environment in the subprocess, which is probably not what you want. Sounds like an XY problem - usually programmatic execution in environments is better done through `conda run`.

Comment: Yes, please include **why** you want to activate a conda environment. Are you trying to run some program that is installed in your conda env with an `os.system` call?

Comment: Hey @merv, I get what you're saying about this being an XY problem (didn't know what that was, so I learned something new), but I have already tried conda run as I put in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The `conda run` command is not to activate an environment, it is to direct a command to run within an environment. So, you want:

```python
import os

## run script1 in TestEnv
os.system("conda run -n TestEnv python script1.py")
## run script2 in TestEnv2
os.system("conda run -n TestEnv2 python script2.py")
```